# Getting a vector of largest keys in vector of maps

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure, key

I have a vector of maps, which looks like this:

```
(def game-vec [{:game 1 :start 123456}
        {:game 2 :start 523456}
        {:game 3 :start 173456}
        {:game 1 :start 123456}
        {:game 1 :start 523456}
        {:game 2 :start 128456}
        {:game 3 :start 123256}])
```

I'd like to take the biggest `:start` time for each `:game`. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is yet another solution

```
user=> (map #(apply max-key :start %) 
            (vals (group-by :game game-vec)))
({:game 1, :start 523456} 
 {:game 2, :start 523456} 
 {:game 3, :start 173456})
```

Comment: I really like how simple this made the problem. It's also the least destructive as it keeps any others keys that may be present in place!

Answer (score 3):

```
(into {} (for [[game times] (group-by :game game-vec)]
           {game (apply max (map :start times))}))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to get all the games from the vector.

maybe something like:

```
(defn game-keys [from]
    (set (map (fn [x] (:game x)) from)))
```

Now we have all the unique games stored somewhere, now for each of those we want the highest value of start. Sort might be useful if we filter out the right games.

```
(defn games [key from] 
  (filter (fn [x] (= (:game x) key)) from))
```

So we can get the games that we want, now we just need the highest of them

```
(defn max-start [lst]
  (first (sort (fn [x y] (> (:start x) (:start y))) lst)))
```

So now we can do:

```
(map (fn [x] (max-start (games x game-vec))) (game-keys game-vec))
```

However that is just one way of doing, there are probably better ways of doing depending on the definition of best.

Comment: (map (fn [x] (:game x)) from) is the smae as (map :game form)

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

```
(defn max-start-per-game [coll]  
        (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k (apply max (map :start v))]) 
                      (group-by :game game-vec))))

=> (max-start-per-game game-vec)
{1 523456, 2 523456, 3 173456}
```

The idea is to get all the data per game in one place and then take out the data for starts. Then just do a max on that.

The more general version:

```
(defn collect [coll sum-key collect]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k (map :start v)])
                (group-by :game game-vec))))

(defn no-good-name
  [coll f key1 key2]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k (f v)])
                (collect coll key1 key2)))


(no-good-name game-vec #(apply max %) :game :start)
 => {1 523456, 2 523456, 3 173456}
```

(using a costum function (called fmap somewhere in contrib) to map over all values of a map would probebly be even better but you can do that your self)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over my last solution with the max function idea from @nickik. I am convinced there is a one-liner in here somewhere :-)

```
(reduce                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 (fn [m x]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   (assoc m (:game x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          (max (:start x)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               (or (m (:game x)) 0))))                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 {}
 game-vec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Functionally very similar to Julian Chastang's code and using `reduce` I have:
`(defn max-start-per-game [games]
  (reduce (fn [res {:keys [game start]}]
    (let [cur-start (get res game 0)
          max-start (max start cur-start)]
      (assoc res game max-start))) 
    {} 
    games))`

`user=> (max-start-per-game game-vec)
{3 173456, 2 523456, 1 523456}`

Alternatively using `group-by`amalloy's code is as succinct as possible.